# GET http://localhost:4200/ 404 (Not Found) after NG Serve

Tags: angular-cli

I have no idea what is happening here. It has worked for weeks without an issue and the application still works on my laptop, but as soon as I pull new changes to my desktop and try to run my app I get this 404 error. I have tried recloning the repo, reinstalling angular/cli, clear cache, reinstalling node modules folder nothing works.

"GET http://localhost:4200/ 404 (Not Found)" and on the page itself it just says Cannot GET /.

Everything compiles no problem so it must be something to do with the angular/cli server. I am completely stumped can't move on until I find a fix. Have not been able to find this same issue anywhere.

Like I said, it works fine on my laptop. I can make changes to the files on my desktop, compile succesfully, push the the changes, pull them onto my laptop, and see them work there.

Any ideas?

--EDIT--

Just tried making a new test project and it serves just fine.

Comment: try the steps in this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli)

Comment: @RahulSingh still nothing

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: I had same issue while working with ng serve. But in my case it was some permission issues with folder inside which the angular application was kept.

Answer (score 5):

Please try to run the command as `ng serve --open` instead of `ng serve` in the git bash. That worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

npm Link did the trick, must have had something to do with a discrepancy between the global and local Angular CLI

Answer (score 1):

After returning to a project after weeks, I was facing the same problem: The server at localhost:4200 responded with "`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`".
After a while I realized that I had previously changed the `<base>` node in `index.html`.

So, I changed it back to `<base href="/">` and the app was working again with `ng serve`.

Stupid, I know, but maybe helpful for somebody.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Same mistake we did and now working fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Go to project folder and use ng serve --open in Cli that will initate your angular configrtion agian